# flex has no effect on this element since it’s not a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with flexbox and its weird reaction, I set flexbox for the parent element and apply `flex: 1 1 100%`, it doesn't work. Firefox Developer Tools are telling me that the parent isn't flex container and to add `display: flex` to the parent.

```css
#dragable_container {
  display: flex;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  min-width: 20rem;
  min-height: 20rem;
  background-color: hsl(157, 90%, 35%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="dragable_container">
    <div class="box" id="dragable"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I have

```
position: absolute;
```

because position: absolute; default behavior trying to fit the content